# Unable to install Just In Time Debugger on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: powershell, exception, updates, visual-studio-2017

I have a clean Windows 2012 R2 with SharePoint 2016. Installed Visual Studio Community 2017, when I try to install the JustInTime Debugger using the VS update I get the following error:

```
The product failed to install the listed workloads and components due to one or more package failures.

Incomplete components
    Just-In-Time debugger (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Debugger.JustInTime,version=15.0.26208.0)

You can search for solutions using the information below, modify your selections for the above workloads and components and retry the installation, or remove the product from your machine.

Following is a collection of individual package failures that led to the incomplete workloads and components above. To search for existing reports of these specific problems, please copy and paste the URL from each package failure into a web browser. If the issue has already been reported, you can find solutions or workarounds there. If the issue has not been reported, you can create a new issue where other people will be able to find solutions or workarounds.

Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.JustInTime,version=15.0.26424.2' failed to install.
    Search URL: https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.JustInTime;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=1
    Impacted components
        Just-In-Time debugger (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Debugger.JustInTime,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Log
        C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170622105625_003_Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.JustInTime.log
    Details
        Command executed: "c:\windows\syswow64\\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -InputFormat None -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -Command "$ErrorActionPreference="""Stop""";$VerbosePreference="""Continue""";$Action="""Modify""";$AppId="""9180617e""";$Packages="""Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet,Microsoft.Net.Component.4.6.1.SDK,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TypeScript.2.2,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.TypeScript,Component.WebSocket,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.Diagnostics,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.Compiler,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Static.Analysis.Tools,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.PortableLibrary,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.CLR,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VisualStudioData,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.AppInsights.Tools,Microsoft.Component.ClickOnce,Microsoft.Net.Component.4.5.TargetingPack,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Debugger.JustInTime,Microsoft.Component.MSBuild,Microsoft.Net.Component.4.6.1.TargetingPack,Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.DevelopmentPrerequisites,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TextTemplating,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Core,Microsoft.Net.Component.4.TargetingPack,Microsoft.Net.Component.4.5.2.TargetingPack,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.IISExpress,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.WebDeploy,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.NCLI,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.LocalDB.Runtime,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.ADAL,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Common.Azure.Tools,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.CMDUtils,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.SSDT,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.DataSources,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web""";[io.file]::ReadAllText("""C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.JustInTime,version=15.0.26424.2\RegisterJustInTimeDebugger.ps1""") | Invoke-Expression; if (!$?) { exit 1603 } elseif ($LastExitCode) { exit $LastExitCode }"
        Return code: 1
        Return code details: Incorrect function.
```

In the log:

```
[10c8:002a][2017-06-22T10:32:43] c:\windows\syswow64\\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -InputFormat None -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -Command "$ErrorActionPreference="""Stop""";$VerbosePreference="""Continue""";$Action="""Modify""";$AppId="""9180617e""";$Packages="""Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet,Microsoft.Net.Component.4.6.1.SDK,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TypeScript.2.2,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.TypeScript,Component.WebSocket,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.Diagnostics,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.Compiler,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Static.Analysis.Tools,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.PortableLibrary,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.CLR,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VisualStudioData,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.AppInsights.Tools,Microsoft.Component.ClickOnce,Microsoft.Net.Component.4.5.TargetingPack,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Debugger.JustInTime,Microsoft.Component.MSBuild,Microsoft.Net.Component.4.6.1.TargetingPack,Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.DevelopmentPrerequisites,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TextTemplating,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Core,Microsoft.Net.Component.4.TargetingPack,Microsoft.Net.Component.4.5.2.TargetingPack,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.IISExpress,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.WebDeploy,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.NCLI,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.LocalDB.Runtime,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.ADAL,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Common.Azure.Tools,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.CMDUtils,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.SSDT,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.DataSources,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web""";[io.file]::ReadAllText("""C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.JustInTime,version=15.0.26424.2\RegisterJustInTimeDebugger.ps1""") | Invoke-Expression; if (!$?) { exit 1603 } elseif ($LastExitCode) { exit $LastExitCode }"
[10c8:002a][2017-06-22T10:32:43] Error: Invoke-Expression : The term 'Invoke-Expression' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.
At line:1 char:1812
+ ... bugger.ps1") | Invoke-Expression; if (!$?) { exit 1603 } elseif ($LastExitCode)  ...
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Invoke-Expression:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

It seems that `Invoke-Expression` is not recognized....how is it possible?